# UWP: Why can't I get a ListView.ItemContainerStyle padding to zero?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I don't seem to be able to set a `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`'s padding to zero.

As you can see from below screenshot, although I've set `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`'s padding to zero and also the padding/margin of the `Border` component contained therein, there's still space left between the two.

Why?

[image: Can't set ListView.ItemContainerStyle padding to zero]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default control template of `ListViewItem`, there is a `VerticalContentAlignment` property, which defaults to **Center**, this determines the vertical centering of internal elements. You can modify this property to **Stretch** in the container style.

```xml
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure if I do understand why I should use stretch when all the paddings and margins are set to zero. I didn't specify a specific height. So, shouldn't the ListView item container just use the content's height?

Comment: `ListViewItem` has a default minimum height, which is 40, so when your single item height is less than this value, the situation you see will appear. You can manually set `ListView.MinHeight=0`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Richard, for enlightening me on this one!